# Proper use of Role.rules.resourceNames for creating pods with limited access to resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-rbac

I am trying to create a Pod that is able to create and update a specific configmap using `Role.rules.resourceNames`. I am able to perform a get request for the resource to the API from within the pod, but I'm not able to create the resource, instead getting

```
$ kubectl logs rbac-test
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "/config/aaa.yaml": configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:rbac-test" cannot create resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

If I remove the `resourceNames` attribute I am able to create the configmap, but I don't necessarily want this pod to be able to create and update configmaps willy-nilly. How can I restrict the serviceAccount's roles so that this pod can manipulate only the named configmap `aaa`?

EDIT

I got some help in the kubernetes slack (thank you, Alan). RBAC happens at the level of the URL so resourceName-restricted authorization can't happen for create URLs since there is no resource name in the URL!

```yaml
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: rbac-test
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  serviceAccountName: rbac-test
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: docker-hub-creds 
  containers:
    - name: rbac-test
      image: bitnami/kubectl
      command: [ "kubectl" ]
      args: [ "apply", "-f", "/config/aaa.yaml" ]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: aaa-config
          mountPath: /config/
  volumes:
    - name: aaa-config
      configMap:
        name: aaa-config

---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: aaa-config
data:
  aaa.yaml: |
    kind: ConfigMap
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: aaa
    data:
      value: na

---
apiVersion: v1     
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: rbac-test

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: rbac-test
rules:
  - apiGroups: [ "" ]
    resources: [ "configmaps" ]
    verbs: [ "get", "create", "update" ]
    resourceNames: [ "aaa" ]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: rbac-test
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: rbac-test
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: rbac-test
```

Answer (score 5):

Note: You cannot restrict create or deletecollection requests by resourceName. For create, this limitation is because the object name is not known at authorization time.

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Answer (score 5):

As mention by Shai Katz in previous answer according to documentation: [Using RBAC Authorization - Referring to resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources)

> You cannot restrict `create` or `deletecollection` requests by `resourceName`. For create, this limitation is because the object name is not known at authorization time.

Solution provided in the edit section - still will not work.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: rbac-test
rules:
  - apiGroups: [ "" ]
    resources: [ "configmaps" ]
    verbs: [ "get", "create", "update" ]
    resourceNames: [ "aaa" ]
```

This config allows you to only get and update existing configmap named `aaa` while the create operation is pointless as this resource cannot be created..

#### How can I restrict the serviceAccount's roles so that this pod can manipulate only the named configmap

You can achieve what you want if you will edit your [Role](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-example)

**Solution 1**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: rbac-test
rules:
  - apiGroups: [ "" ]             #this rule will allow to update existing configmap aaa referenced by resourcename 
    resources: [ "configmaps" ]
    verbs: [ "get", "update" ]    
    resourceNames: [ "aaa" ]
  - apiGroups: [ "" ]             #this rule will allow you to create configmaps
    resources: [ "configmaps" ]
    verbs: [ "get", "create" ]
```

It can be verified by executing commands below:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i update configmaps/aaa --as=system:serviceaccount:default:rbac-test
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i create configmaps/new-aaa --as=system:serviceaccount:default:rbac-test
yes
```

However, in this scenario `rbac-test pod/sa` can perform `update` action by executing `kubectl replace` command f.e:

`$ kubectl replace -f /config/aaa.yaml`

I you are interested with `$ kubectl apply` probably you should use verb `patch` like in the example below.

```
  - apiGroups: [ "" ]       
    resources: [ "configmaps" ]
    verbs: [ "get", "patch" ]    
    resourceNames: [ "aaa" ]
```

**Solution 2** - More restrictive approach.

Instead of giving your `serviceAccount: rbac-test` permission to create configs in k8s api. Please consider creating two configmaps:

a)

```
$ kubectl create cm aaa ### an empty "aaa" configmap
```

b)

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: aaa-config
data:
  aaa.yaml: |
    kind: ConfigMap
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: aaa
    data:
      value: na
EOF
```

This `configmap` will be populated to the `POD` using [volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-specific-path-in-the-volume). `Configmap.data` will be stored inside the `pods` directory under `/config/aaa.yaml`

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: aaa
data:
  value: na
```

Configure this `RBAC Role`:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: rbac-test
rules:
  - apiGroups: [ "" ]             #this rule will allow to patch existing empty "aaa" configmap aaa referenced by resourcename 
    resources: [ "configmaps" ]
    verbs: [ "get", "patch" ]    
    resourceNames: [ "aaa" ]
```

In this scenario you will have preconfigured `aaa` empty `configmap` and your `pod` with associated `rbac-test serviceAccount` will be able to perform `patch` request using provided YAML manifest stored in `/config/aaa.yaml` inside the `Pod`.

```
$ kubectl auth can-i patch configmaps/aaa --as=system:serviceaccount:default:rbac-test
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i create configmaps/new-aaa --as=system:serviceaccount:default:rbac-test
no
```

To check which verbs you can use in `RBAC` for `ConfigMap` execute:

```
$ kubectl api-resources -o wide | grep configmap
configmaps                        cm                                          true         ConfigMap                        [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
```